# Fitting a long sentence into a narrow table cell

Tags: tables, multirow, wrap

This is my table (the a's and b's replace actual letters). How do I make the sentences that are all b's to fit in their cells without changing the width of the cells?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ K{1.7cm}|K{1.4cm}|K{2.3cm}|K{1.4cm}|K{1cm}|K{1cm}|K{1.4cm}|K{1cm} } \hline

\multirow{6}{*}{bbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb} & \multirow{3}{*}{bbbbb bbbbbb} & aaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-8}
 &  & aaaaaaaaaaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-8}
 &  & aaaaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{2-8}
 & \multirow{3}{*}{bbbbbb bbbbbbbb}  & aaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-8}
 &  & aaaaaaaaaaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-8}
 &  & aaaaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \hline      
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

My header includes:

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
```

Thanks!

Comment: try `p` column type instead of `m`

Comment: still looks the same

Comment: welcome to tex.se!please extend and merge your code snippets to one small, but complete document begining with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}, which demonstrate your problem.  it seems that your use of `multirow` is wrong. column, where is used had to be `p{..}` type and then`\multirow{...}{=}{...text ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

your use of `multirow` is wrong. for broke text in cell into more lines you need to do one of the following:

- defined width of `multirow` cell, for example `\multirow{4}{2cm}{ ... text in cell ...}`
- if you have insttaled recent version of `multirow` package (recommended) , than you can use `\multirow{4}{=}{ ... text in cell ...}`, where `{=}` consider defined column type. for breaking of text into more lines than column had to be `p{...}` (or `m` or `b`) type or `X` tape, if you use `tabularx`.

**edit:** complete *mwe*. with exploiting features of recent `multirow` package you obtain clear and concise code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering} % for horizontal centering of multirow cell content 
    \begin{tabular}{ K{2cm}|K{1.5cm}|K{2.3cm}|c|c|c|c|c} \hline
\multirow{6}{=}{bbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb} 
    &   \multirow{3}{=}{bbbbb bbbbbb} 
        & aaa   & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-8}
    &   & aaaaaaaaaaa 
                & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-8}
    &   & aaaaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{2-8}
    &   \multirow{3}{=}{bbbbbb bbbbbbbb}  
        & aaa   & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-8}
    &   & aaaaaaaaaaa 
                & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-8}
    &   & aaaaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a parbox like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c|c|c|K{1.4cm}|K{1cm}|K{1cm}|K{1.4cm}|K{1cm} } \hline

\multirow{6}{*}{\parbox{1.9cm}{\centering bbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{1.7cm}{\centering bbbbb bbbbbb}} & aaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-8}
 &  & aaaaaaaaaaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-8}
 &  & aaaaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{2-8}
 & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{1.7cm}{\centering bbbbbb bbbbbbbb}}  & aaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-8}
 &  & aaaaaaaaaaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-8}
 &  & aaaaa & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\ \hline      
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]